# skeletonization (thinning) of small images not giving expected results - python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I am trying to implement a skeletonization of small images. But I am not getting an expected results. I tried also `thin()` and `medial_axis()` but nothing seems to work as expected. I am suspicious that this problem occurs because of the small resolutions of images. Here is the code:

```
import cv2
from numpy import asarray
import numpy as np

# open image
file = "66.png"
img_grey = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
afterMedian = cv2.medianBlur(img_grey, 3)
thresh = 140

# threshold the image
img_binary = cv2.threshold(afterMedian, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# make binary image
arr = asarray(img_binary)
binaryArr = np.zeros(asarray(img_binary).shape)
for i in range(0, arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0, arr.shape[1]):
        if arr[i][j] == 255:
            binaryArr[i][j] = 1
        else:
            binaryArr[i][j] = 0

# perform skeletonization
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize

cv2.imshow("binary arr", binaryArr)
backgroundSkeleton = skeletonize(binaryArr)

# convert to non-binary image
bSkeleton = np.zeros(arr.shape)
for i in range(0, arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0, arr.shape[1]):
        if backgroundSkeleton[i][j] == 0:
            bSkeleton[i][j] = 0
        else:
            bSkeleton[i][j] = 255

cv2.imshow("background skeleton", bSkeleton)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The results are:

[image] [image]

I would expect something more like this:

[image]

This applies to similar shapes also:

[image] [image]

Expectation:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Or it will truly will not be possible with such small pictures, because I tried skeletonization on bigger images and it worked just fine. Original images:

[image] [image]

Comment: It's the white area (which is the background in your images) which is being skeletonised; why not invert the image to skeletonise the object in the middle?

Comment: Because I need the skeleton of background

Comment: Yes looks like a resolution issue. You are seeing indents but there simply isn't enough pixels to get the expected lines. You could upsample the binary images I guess but I dont know what your application is or what you'd get once you convert back to the original resolution if you had to do that.

Comment: The upsampling is good idea, I will try it.

Comment: You could try the skeleton in DIPlib: `import diplib as dip; sk = dip.EuclideanSkeleton(bin)`. The 2nd input argument can be used to adjust how many branches are preserved or removed. https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/binary.html#dip-EuclideanSkeleton-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-String-CL-dip-String-CL

Comment: That looks good, but can you help me create a binary image? I tried something like: ```a = dip.Image((im.Size(0), im.Size(1)), 1); for all a[i,j]=True/False (pseudo code)``` but the image is still not binary: ```Image is not binary in function: EuclideanSkeleton```.

Comment: Please add `@Cris` to your comment to ping me, otherwise I don’t know you’ve answered my comment.

Comment: In DIPlib you can use any NumPy array as an input to DIPlib functions. An array with logical values is seen as a binary image (such as `array>0`).  Create a binary DIPlib image from scratch, use `dip.Image((im.Size(0), im.Size(1)), 1, 'BIN')`, but you shouldn’t need to do this. You can also explicitly cast an array to a DIPlib image with `img=dip.Image(array)`, or back with `array=np.array(img)`.

Comment: Using your code above, after the binarization where you create `afterMedian`, you can do `dip.EuclideanSkeleton(afterMedian>thresh)`.

Comment: thank you for all the tips I will get back to this soon

Comment: @CrisLuengo, @Cris Luengo Hi, I have come to a problem. When I Make a dip Image with ```'BIN' ``` keyword, then the dip.EuclideanSkeleton() results in error that says ```Image is not scalar```. When I do not specify ```'BIN' ``` keyword the new error says that ```Image is not binary```. Well I am now confused. I tried to fill the boolean values as well as int values to the image which is being skeletonized.

Comment: @nocturne if it complains that the image is not scalar it is because your image has more than one sample per pixel. I’m not sure how you create your image, maybe post a new question with code.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, @Cris Luengo Hi, I was indexing the picture with ```a[i][j]``` which does not worked for with my initialization ```a=dip.Image((im.Size(0), im.Size(1)), 1, 'BIN')``` so I changed that 1 in initialization, hence the image was no scalar. No I am indexing with ```a[i,j]``` and it works. The skeleton is not what I exactly wanted but it is much better and I think I can work with that (I used ```"two neighbors"``` parameter), I also upsampled it for better results. Many thanks to you.

Comment: @CrisLuengo You may post an answer so I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the skeleton in DIPlib ([`dip.EuclideanSkeleton`](https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/binary.html#dip-EuclideanSkeleton-dip-Image-CL-dip-Image-L-dip-String-CL-dip-String-CL)):

```py
import numpy as np
import diplib as dip
import cv2

file = "66.png"
img_grey = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
afterMedian = cv2.medianBlur(img_grey, 3)
thresh = 140

bin = afterMedian > thresh

sk = dip.EuclideanSkeleton(bin, endPixelCondition='three neighbors')

dip.viewer.Show(bin)
dip.viewer.Show(sk)
dip.viewer.Spin()
```

The `endPixelCondition` input argument can be used to adjust how many branches are preserved or removed. `'three neighbors'` is the option that produces the most branches.

The code above produces branches also towards the corners of the image. Using `'two neighbors'` prevents that, but produces fewer branches towards the object as well. The other way to prevent it is to set `edgeCondition='object'`, but in this case the ring around the object becomes a square on the image boundary.

---

To convert the DIPlib image `sk` back to a NumPy array, do

```py
sk = np.array(sk)
```

`sk` is now a Boolean NumPy array (values `True` and `False`). To create an array compatible with OpenCV simply cast to `np.uint8` and multiply by 255:

```py
sk = np.array(sk, dtype=np.uint8)
sk *= 255
```

Note that, when dealing with NumPy arrays, you generally don't need to loop over all pixels. In fact, it's worth trying to avoid doing so, as loops in Python are extremely slow.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the scikit-image is much better choice than cv2 here.
since the package define Bit functions, if you are playing with BW images, then try this ready to use code:
[skeletonize](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_skeleton.html)

note: if process pass the image details, then don’t upsample the input at first until you tried other functions:again use skimage [morphology](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html#binary-opening) functions to enhance details which in such case your code will be work on bigger area of images too. You could look [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/filters/plot_attribute_operators.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-filters-plot-attribute-operators-py).